# ADF - Get value from a copy activity

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-factory

I am trying to run a SOQL (SalesForce SQL) in a Copy data activity in ADF to count no of records with a where condition and write it into a .csv file into an Azure Blob storage. The query works fine and write the total number of records in the .csv file. Eventually I would like to use output value(count of records) of the copy data activity as an input for the Stored Proc activity as shown in the snip below.

[image: ADF pipeline]

SOQL used in the Copy data activity:

`Select COUNT() from Accounts WHERE SystemModstamp > 2022-09-01T17:11:54Z AND SystemModstamp <= 2022-09-01T17:23:20Z`

Stored Proc Parameter Value:

`@activity('CopyObject').output.value`

I am not very sure what should the stored proc parameter be used here. The stored proc writes the output of the copy data activity into a table in db. It works fine when I use `@activity('CopyObject').output.rowscopied` but this is a wrong expression as it always gives result as 1. I however need the expression to get the value of the copy data activity.

Would really appreciate any help/guidance.

Comment: Use a Lookup to get a scalar value like the result of a count.  Alternatively consider a Script activity which supports output variables.

Answer (score 0):

The expression @activity('CopyObject').output.rowscopied provides the count of records copied between the source and sink and since your expression in sql is count(*) , hence you would always see the value as 1.
For you to get that count, as stated in comment you need to use a look up activity or a script activity to get the same sql query value and leverage it as an sp parameter value

Comment: I did use lookup activity to get the value of the count and it works fine, the problem is when I try to pass this value as a parameter to the next activity (which is a Stored Proc), I am not sure of the expression that should be used in the Value field under Stored Proc parameters.
I tried using the below expression after adding a lookup activity post copy data.

@activity('Lookup CopyObjectBlobOutput').output.value

Comment: @activity('Lookup CopyObjectBlobOutput').output.value
I get error when I use this expression: The expression 'activity('Lookup CopyObjectBlobOutput').output.value' cannot be evaluated because property 'value' doesn't exist, available properties are 'firstRow, effectiveIntegrationRuntime, billingReference, durationInQueue'.

Comment: Hey @Priyanka2304, You need to enable the firstRow only property in lookup activity and use the below expression @activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow

Comment: Hi @Nandan, I did try with the expression as well but it gives the below error:

Cannot create Sql Source. Please double check the connection string, stored procedure are set with correct format. Error: The value of the property 'Value' is invalid for the stored procedure parameter 'CountRecords'.